# How to compare a string with a value inside of object in mongoDB & Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql-aggregation

i am receiving a string "city" from "req.body"

my function:

```js
async function searchProject(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { code, archiveNumber, air, city, municipality, origin } = req.body;
  console.log(city);
  try {
    const projects = await Project.find({
      $or: [
        { code: { $regex: code ?? "" } },
        { archiveNumber },
        { air },
        {
          city: {
            $in: [city, "$city.value"],
          },
        },
        { municipality },
        { origin },
      ],
    });

    if (!projects)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Pas de projet trouvée" });
    res.status(200).json(projects);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
}
```

i am using $or operator to get projects that matches at least on the values that receive from "req.body", all other values seem to work but "city".

in my document, here is how city looks like:

```js
       "city": [
            {
                "id": "62ed0121f58a5ed78ac05a85",
                "value": "City 1"
            }
        ],
```

now how can i compare a "city" which i get from "req.body" with "city.value" ?

Comment: You can try this filter: `'city.value': req.body.city`.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, but it didn't work, i am getting the same results all documents

Comment: use $elemMatch https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

i tried:

```js
const projects = await Project.find({
  $or: [
    { code: { $regex: code ?? "" } },
    { archiveNumber },
    { air },
    { municipality },
    { origin },
  ],
}).elemMatch("city", {
  value: city,
});
```

and it worked
thanks to
Siddhesh Khadapkar